# mongo store document meta data

Tags: mongodb

Which is the best way to store meta data for a document, in the document itself or in separate collection?

I am working with a collection that has data like this:

```
{
   status: {
       joined: Date,
       retired: [{
           on: Date,
           comment: String,
           reinstated: {
               on: Date,
               comment: String
           }
       }],
       suspended: [{
           on: Date,
           comment: String,
           reinstated: {
               on: Date,
               comment: String
           }
       }],
       //.....
```

I need to keep a log of when and who performs these changes, but I am not sure if I should add the metadata to each element or have a collection like Log.

```
// Log collection
{
    by: UserId,
    on: Date,
    verb: String,
    object: ObjectId,
    comment: String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store meta data with document for few reasons:

1. It will look more natural if you keep the document and its metadata together.
2. When you load document you can easily [exclude](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) metadata from the document to keep your documents light when metadata is not needed:

   db.items.find( { }, { metadata : 0 } );
3. You can easily use paging to [retrieve](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements) metadata using `$slice`:

   db.items.find({}, {metadata:{$slice: [20, 10]}}) // skip 20, at most 10

But, also keep in mind that:

1. The size limit of a document is 16MB. If you're planning to have a lot of metadata, then better go with a separate collection. But I usually start from embedding the data, and later migrate it to a separate collection if it becomes too big.

2 .If you need to show the metadata across all documents somewhere, like in a grid, it can be a pain to load it, apply paging, etc.

Comment: So if I wanted (as a secondary feature) to display the metadata history from a variety of collections (i.e. Users, Vendors, Customers) using the metadata would you recommend having a Log collection and duplicating data?

Comment: I think if you wanted to display the metadata history it would be beneficial to have a separate collection, but also keep the most recent metadata embedded in the original document.